# How to force JS to ignore a li element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have implemented [jquery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

(this is just an example to simulate the real code)

```js
let availableTags = [   
      undefined,    // this is only a header and its results to undefined due to a lack of Id
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];

    $('#tags').autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
                                                    
              minLength: 0,
                        
              focus: function (event, ui) { 
                                              
                       if(!ui.item){ 

                          // add code here

                       }
                                                                                        
              },
                        
              select: function (event, ui) {                                            

                    //...    

              },
      })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

The first `li` element of the `ul` is only a header (not a real `li` option)
, therefore I don't want it to be selected at all.

I managed to prevent `click events` on it but it is still **"sensitive"** to other events
like `mouseenter` `mouseover` and more I can activate those events by using the keyboard
`keydown`

**how can I force `JS` to ignore the first `li` element from been triggered at all
not even via keyboard ?**

**EDIT:**
By the way, I can control the first `li` tag  to be `div` \ `span` or
any other tag (just remember that that tag will be enclosed in a `ul`)

**EDIT-2:**
The header should only be **displayed** to actioned at all by no JS `event` (mouse, keyboard etc.) and the header should be `undefined` to match the real code

Comment: it should be displayed but not selected..right ?

Comment: yes correct only displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the data as object with `category` and `label` as attributes in `availableTags` data array; and also need to implement `_renderMenu` of your custom auto complete functionality.

```js
$.widget("custom.mycomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _create: function () {
    this._super();
    this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
  },
  _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
    var that = this,
      currentCategory = "";
    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
      var li;
      if (item.category != currentCategory) {
        ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
        currentCategory = item.category;
      }
      li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
      if (item.category) {
        li.attr("aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label);
      }
    });
  }
});

let availableTags = [
  { label: "AppleScript", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Asp", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "BASIC", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "C", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "C++", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Clojure", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "COBOL", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "ColdFusion", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Erlang", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Fortran", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Groovy", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Haskell", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Java", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "JavaScript", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Lisp", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Perl", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "PHP", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Python", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Ruby", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Scala", category: "Langauges" },
  { label: "Scheme", category: "Langauges" }
];

$('#tags').mycomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  minLength: 0,
  focus: function (event, ui) {
    if (!ui.item) {
      //code goes here
    }
  },
  select: function (event, ui) {
    //code goes here
  }
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete-category {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .2em .4em;
    margin: .6em 0 .2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that worked, but still the question remains how to force a tag (like `li`) to be unresponsive to any JS `event` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add some class to your `ul` by `autocomplete("widget").addClass("whatever");`  then in css add `pointer-events: none;`

```js
let availableTags = [
            "header",    // this is only a header and its results to undefined due to a lack of Id
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];

        $('#tags').autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            minLength: 0,
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                debugger

                if (!ui.item) {
                   // add code here
                }
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                //...
            },
        }).autocomplete("widget").addClass("whatever");
```

```css
 ul.whatever li:first-child {
            background-color:red;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: sorry it's not good I can still run over the header by the keyboard, just press down arrow. and don't change the header to `string`  to resemble to real code it should result in undefined

Comment: @Ben.S Ok you have to override `_renderItem` of autocomplete.  Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/m6zvf/12/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `disabled` property in the availableTags to indicate whether or not this should be selected and handle the result of selection in the `source()` method of the autocomplete call.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    {value: "COBOL", disabled: false},
    {value: "JAVA", disabled: false},
    {value: "PHP", disabled: false},
    {value: "ReactJS", disabled: false},
    {value: "NodeJS", disabled: true},
    {value: "ActionScript", disabled: true},
  ];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.item.disabled) {
        alert('Please choose a valid option')
        //  suppress disabled items
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input id="tags" />
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3q1fwsc/)

Comment: that is not good because I can still hover on that disabled option, I need the disabled option to be **completely ignored by all events** and I need the disabled option to be undefined to resemble the real code

Comment: ofcourse you can customize this to achieve what you want.. this is just to give an idea